# Groovy: Mockito UnfinishedStubbingException using verify (and inline mocks)

Tags: gradle, groovy, mockito, final, stubbing

I'm trying to `verify` the calling of a method on a `FileChooser`.

I'm coding in Groovy, and this appears to be the problem.

I'm using the "incubating" Mockito feature which enables you to mock even a `final` class.

Code is:

```
    FileChooser mockFC = mock(FileChooser.class)
    doReturn(mockFC).when(spyCH).getFileChooser()
    ...
    verify( mockFC, times( 1 )).showOpenDialog( any() )
```

This gives:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
>  
>   Unfinished stubbing detected here:
>   ...
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:55)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:197)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:217)
>       at core.ConsoleHandlerFTs.shouldShowFileChooserDialogOnEnteringO(ConsoleHandlerFTs.groovy:91)

(NB line 91 is the `verify` line)

... and then goes on to talk about `final` method (`showOpenDialog` is not `final`), missing `whenReturn` (not applicable), etc.

The Mockito in my build.gradle in GRADLE_HOME is version 2.7.22.
`FileChooser` is `javafx.stage.FileChooser`.
Java version is 1.8.0_121.

I created an entirely new Gradle project... and did the same thing, with just Java files. Mocking worked OK, test passed!

By "adding back" the bits and pieces which make Groovy function in a Gradle project I seemed to get to the problem: after

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
```

and (in dependencies)

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.0-alpha-1'
```

the problem reoccurred. That is, even without having created any .groovy files.  I then tried earlier versions of groovy, down to 2.3.11.  Same result.

From searching I thought the "bytebuddy" package might be implicated but adding the following line to dependencies ensured that no earlier versions were present in GRADLE_HOME:

```
compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.6.11'
```

Still getting `UnfinishedStubbingException` come up when I run the Groovy test file.

Comment: I don't have this issue. I did a Java test and it works well.

Comment: What version of Mockito? Groovy? In which package is FileChooser?

Comment: Can you update your question to be minimal after the new information you have collected? Have you tried Groovy2 versions?

Comment: @tkruse chopped out some of the dead wood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Workaround" ... for anyone who's typically moving from Java to Groovy.

To learn Groovy I'm actually following a book, *Groovy in Action, 2nd Ed*, co-authored among others by [JON SKEET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)!

I have now got to the part about testing, which is sort of designed into the language, as well as taking advantage of some of Groovy's amazing power.

It appears that Groovy's Spock testing framework is the way to go... and mocking `final` classes turns out to be possible with `GroovyMock`. I was able to write a test to do the job:

```
class XXX extends Specification {

    @Rule
    public TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream()
    def xxx(){
        given:
        FileChooser fc = GroovyMock( FileChooser )
        ConsoleHandler ch = Spy( ConsoleHandler ){
            getFileChooser() >> fc
        }
        ch.setMaxLoopCount 10
        systemInMock.provideLines( "o" )

        when:
        com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup( {} )
        ch.loop()
        Thread.sleep( 2000L ) // needs improvement with a Latch or something!

        then:
        1 * fc.showOpenDialog( _ )
    }
}
```

... it'd still be nice if some Groovy *übermind* (Jon, are you there?) could find out why Mockito produces this `UnfinishedStubbingException` in Groovy.

NB you don't seem to be able to use `GroovyMock` in isolation within a Mockito test... it appears to be part of the Spock framework.